# ~/.barshrc not working as expected

Tags: linux, bash

In my understanding `bashrc` is run each time a new shell is opened. To test this I added `echo 'hello'` to `bashrc`.

Yet, when I open a new shell, there's regretfully no kind greeting.

I'm running on ubuntu 12.04

**aditional info**:

I read that all shell clients need to be closed before `bashrc` can update. I listed them using `ps aux | awk '{print $7}' | grep -v "?"` which returned

```
TTY
tty4
tty5
tty2
tty3
tty6
tty1
pts/0
pts/0
pts/0
pts/0
pts/0
```

I don't understand this output. Do i need to close all these for `bashrc` to update?

Answer (score 0):

`.bashrc` is run by any interactive bash shell that is started (new terminal window, `bash` used in another bash prompt...). So this mostly excludes invocations of `bash -c <command>`, `bash <somescript>` and the bash interpreter implicitly started to run bash files.

And there is no condition for taking into account the `.bashrc` update: any new bash instance will see the version you just saved.

Comment: Oops, typo only in question. Thus this should mean that if I add `. /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh` to `~/.bashrc` this file would be run on each startup of bash?

Comment: Yes, each time you start a command prompt.

Comment: Okay, Yet that doesn't work? Should I open a new SO question?

Comment: First check that .bashrc is actually called (make it export some environment variable: `export BASHRCHASRUN=Yes`). If you can't see that envar in the shells you start, then yes... Otherwise wonder why . bashrc is not really calling your other shell (or why that shell doesn't run).